# Pyomo + asNMPC framework

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, pyomo

I'm trying to work with Pyomo and an external framework that allows for asNMPC optimization (from this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/303097036_Framework_in_PYOMO_for_the_assessment_and_implementation_of_asNMPC_controllers)).

I installed the version of Pyomo they tested with (v 4.1.10519) and made the changes to the core Pyomo files they requested but I get the following error when I try to run one of the test files (Penicillin_asNMPC.py):

```
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib    /python2.7/site-packages/pyomo/dae/plugins/colloc.py", line 482, in     reduce_collocation_points
  if diffset.type() is not DifferentialSet:
NameError: global name 'DifferentialSet' is not defined
```

Comparing this version of Pyomo to some comments online seems to indicated that there used to be a file called differential.py but it may have been renamed to contset.py. Meaning that 'DifferentialSet' was changed to the variable 'ContinuousSet'. However, since I followed all the requested changes and I'm using the recommend version of Pyomo, I figured that I should not be having this problem.

Just wondering if anyone has had any issues with using this framework/has any helpful advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error you're seeing my guess is that the old version of Pyomo was not uninstalled completely. You should uninstall Pyomo using the script mentioned in [this](http://www.pyomo.org/blog/2015/12/26/updating-to-pyomo-41) blog post and then reinstall the new version.